Getting error while using "^z" as an indicator to end CreateTextFile application bellow
I am learning how to create a text file using Java and store it. However, I am getting an error" Invalid input. Please try again." while entering "^z" end-of-file indicator.
My code is as below:
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Formatter;
import java.lang.SecurityException;
import java.util.FormatterClosedException;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CreateTextFile {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // open clients.txt,output data to the file the close clients.txt
        try (Formatter output = new Formatter("clients.txt")){
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            
            System.out.printf("%s%n%s%n?", 
                    "Enter account number, first name, last name and balance.",
                    "Enter end-of-file indicator to end input.");
            while(input.hasNext()) {
                //loop until end-of-file indicator
                try {//output new record to file; assume valid input
                    output.format("%d %s %s %.2f%n", input.nextInt(),input.next(),input.next(),input.nextDouble());
                }
                catch(NoSuchElementException elementException) {
                    System.err.println("Invalid input. Please try again.");
                    input.nextLine();// discard input so user can try again
                }
                System.out.print("? ");
            }
            
        }
        catch(SecurityException | FileNotFoundException | FormatterClosedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}


? 100 Bob Blue 24.98
? 200 Steve Green -345.67
? 300 Pam White 0.00
? 400 Sam Red -42.16
? 500 Sue Yellow 224.62
? ^Z
These are my input.

for Windows (console) usually CTRL-Z at beginning of line means to close the standard input; for Linux it is CTRL-D

Hello Juan, in the double number, change 24.98 to 24,98.

Welcome to stack overflow!
Generally, Ctrl-z is not an end-of-file indicator. In fact, there is no EOF character defined for the ASCII character set. There is a Ctrl-d character, EOT, or end of transfer, which is usually the best option, since most "terminal" applications responds to it by closing any external connections and shut down and exit.
However, the decision to shut down a connection depending on the input is entirely up to the application.
Your program works fine if you replace ctrl-z with ctrl-d, assuming a unix like terminal, e.g. bash.
As a courtesy to the user, the program should explicitly tell what the "end-of-file" indicator is.
